# Accumulation point and two consecutive terms of a sequence: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (x_{n+1} -x_{n}) = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits, convergence-divergence

I have two questions:

1. Let $(x_n)_{n\ge 0}$ be a sequence satisfying $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (x_{n+1} -x_{n}) = 0$. Can you give some weak conditions for $(x_n)_{n\ge 0}$ to have an accumulation point? (I already know about the "bounded" sufficient condition.)
2. Assume that two sequences $(x_n)_{n\ge 0}$ and $(y_n)_{n\ge 0}$ have their accumulation points respectively, $x^*$ and $y^*$. Assume further that:
   \begin{align}
   \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (x_{n+1} -x_{n}) &= 0 \\
   \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (y_{n+1} -y_{n}) &= 0 \\
   x_{n+1} - x_{n} &= f(x_n,y_n)\quad \forall n,
   \end{align}
   where $f$ is some continuous function. Now if I take the limit, do I get $0 = f(x^*,y^*)$?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Presumably, you want $f$ to be continuous?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews oh yes $f$ should be continuous so that the limit can be applied. I forgot that. Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A weaker condition than boundedness would be $(x_n)$ has a bounded subsequence. In fact, this is equivalent to having an accumulation point.
2. Since such a sequence can have several different accumulation points, the answer in general is no. Even if $f(x_n,y_n)$ converges, $x_n$ and $y_n$ may not converge. Let $(x_n)$ be the sequence
   $$
   0,\frac12,1,\frac12,0,\frac13,\frac23,1,\frac23,\frac13,0,\frac14,\frac24,\frac34,1,\frac34,\frac24,\frac14,0,\dots
   $$
   Let $y_n=x_{n+1}$ and $f(x,y)=y-x$. Then $x_{n+1}-x_n$ and $y_{n+1}-y_n$ converge to $0$ and $f(x_n,y_n)=y_n-x_n=x_{n+1}-x_n$.  But the set of accumulation points of $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ is $[0,1]$. So $f(x^*,y^*)=0$ only if $x^*=y^*$.